# Using oAuth in a ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I recently followed a tutorial about [token authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and I would like to have the token endpoint set to `/api/v1/login`. In order to get it not interfered with the api i build, I added `config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Login Route v1", "api/v1/login");` to my WebApiConfig.cs. In order to get the oAuth token to the right spot I changed the Startup.cs to

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Project.Startup))]
namespace Project
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            //Rest of code is here;
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/v1/login"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the endpoint remains under `/token`, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach was absolutely right, but unfortunately this code was in the project another time with a `/token` PathString, so it overwrote this configuration.